# Python: Do I alter an object by getting a parameter, or by passing as a parameter? OOP

Tags: python, oop

I am laying out the framework for a blackjack simulator.

I have both a `Player` class, and a `Deck` class. I need to deal the players cards. Should I do this by passing the `Player` into a `Deck` function, like so:

```
class Deck:
    def give_cards(self, player, numcards):
        player.hand.append('function that returns numcards'):
        return player
```

Or should I have the player have a function, that accepts either a deck or card list as an input?

```
class Player:
    def grab_cards(self, deck)
        self.hand.append(deck.'function that returns numcards')
```

I apologize if this isn't enough information, I will gladly edit. I'm just not sure what to google for this one. I'm sure I could make both work, but stylistically and best design I am curious. Thanks all.

Comment: This question seems a bit to broad for Stackoverflow.  But does a player pickup cards, or do cards hand themselves to a player?

Comment: If you're trying to model the real world (not necessarily advisable), maybe  have a `Dealer` which uses a `Deck` and `Player`s. There are no right answers, but maybe look at [CRCs](http://c2.com/doc/oopsla89/paper.html)

Comment: Neither function appears to be mutating the deck to account for the cards being dealt.

Answer (score 1):

You should do neither. Split that task into two parts:

- Getting cards from the deck
- Handing cards to a player

I would also use a bit different names for the methods, as `get` strongly suggests that the method will return the caller something (without side-effect), which is not what is happening.

Code (to be adjusted to your actual implementation):

```
class Deck:
    def extract_cards(self, numcards):
        # extract cards from the deck
        cards = self.cards[:numcards]
        del self.cards[:numcards]
        # return that list of card objects
        return cards 

class Player:
    def add_cards(self, cards)
        # simply add the given cards to this player's hand
        self.hand.append(cards)
```

You would do the operation like this:

```
player.add_cards(deck.extract_cards(5))
```

That way one class does not need to know about the other.